# Lightweight database migration library or framework for C#

Tags: library, database, c#

I am looking for a way to easily manage SQL-based database migrations in a C# application. Coming from a Java backgroud, I know Flyway. I am looking for something similar - lightweight, easy to understand, stable.

I could potentially use Flyway, but I would ideally like C# integration and not be dependent on Java.

I have looked at FluentMigrator (https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator), but it does not seem to support SQL-based migrations.

I am aware of Entity Frameworks Code First, but I need more direct control of the SQL.

Requirements:

SQL-based migrations possible
Autorun pending migrations on application startup
Supports SQL Server 2014
Ideally written in C#
I hope I have made my needs clear. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken FluentMigrator does support SQL migrations

[Fluent-Interface](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Fluent-Interface) scroll to the "Execute Expression" section

```
Execute.Script("myscript.sql");
Execute.EmbeddedScript("UpdateLegacySP.sql");
Execute.Sql("DELETE TABLE Users");
```

Comment: Thanks - seems to be the best bet :)